# ¿Cómo compruebo qué tipo o nombre de la variable superglobal es?

Tags: php, funciones, php7

Tengo la siguiente **función que me valida los campos requeridos si existen o están vacíos** de los datos que me llegan de un formulario:

```
/**
 * @param array $_superglobal ($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_SESSION, etc...)
 * @param array $fields nombre indice del campo a validar
 * @return void
 */
function requireds( $_superglobal, $fields ): void 
{
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) 
    {
        if ( !isset($_superglobal[$field]) ) json_response("'{$field}' es requerido");
        if ( empty(trim($_superglobal[$field])) ) json_response("El campo '{$field}' está vacío");
    }
}

// Compruebo los campos requeridos 
requireds( $_POST, ['titulo', 'resumen', 'contenido'] );
requireds( $_FILES, ['portada'] );
```

No hallo información acerca de cómo puedo hacer un condicional que me valide si es un `$_FILES` que sería la excepción a POST y GET. Si pudiese lograr de alguna manera comprobar si se trata de esta superglobal en especifico, podría aplicarle un tratamiento diferente.

> `json_response()` Es simplemente otra función que en caso de ejecutarse, envía el mensaje, realiza un echo en formato json y detiene la ejecución del proceso.

Comment: **NOTA:** Me gustaría obviar que puedo crear una función exclusivamente para los `$_FILES` por que la idea es aprender algo nuevo de la gente increíble de este lugar.

Comment: Definitivamente, deberías crear una función exclusiva para archivos y, de cualquier forma, no le veo mucho sentido a la función actual, porque solo revisas que cada campo exista y no esté vacío, pero no haces validaciones como longitud, valor máximo/mínimo, etc.

Comment: Hola @Triby, sí es cierto, lo que pasa es que no es relevante meter todo el código sabiendo que sólo necesito obtener un booleano de que el parámetro recibido es `$_FILES`. Pero finalmente lo conseguí de manera muy sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

**Mi solución simple:**

```
/**
 * @param array $_superglobal ($_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, $_SESSION, etc...)
 * @param array $fields nombre indice del campo a validar
 * @return void
 */
function requireds( $_superglobal, $fields ): void 
{
    foreach ( $fields as $field ) 
    {

        if ( !isset($_superglobal[$field]) ) 
            json_response("Al parecer no recibí el campo '{$field}'");

        if ( $_superglobal === $_FILES ) {
            if ( empty($_superglobal[$field]) )
                json_response("El adjunto '{$field}' está vacío");
        }
        else {
            if ( empty(trim($_superglobal[$field])) )
                json_response("El campo '{$field}' está vacío");
        }
    }
}
```

Entendiendo que `$_FILES` es una [variable superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php), la variable enviada como argumento, sólo será compatible con la segunda condición sí es exactamente igual a la variable superglobal justo aquí: `if ( $_superglobal === $_FILES )` sin importar que el contenido de `$_superglobal` este vacío.

**¿Qué ocurre en el caso Método $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION?**
La segunda condición de la función pasa al `else` porque el contenido de la variable enviada es diferente al contenido del `$_FILES`

> **NOTA:** No incluí más validaciones para no generar tanto ruido en el código.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Si es meramente educativo, una solución posible sería usar un switch donde los `case` se comparen con un valor *booleano* y en ellas valides las superglobales que esperes.

```
function requireds( $_superglobal, $fields ): void
{
    foreach ( $fields as $field )
    {   
        if ( !isset($_superglobal[$field]) )
            json_response("Al parecer no recibí el campo '{$field}'");

        switch( true ) { 
            case $_superglobal === $_FILES:
                if ( empty($_superglobal[$field]) )
                    json_response("El adjunto '{$field}' está vacío");
                break;

            case $_superglobal === $_GET:
                // Cosas
                break;

            case $_superglobal === $_POST:
                // Más cosas
                break;

            case $_superglobal === $_SESSION:
                // Y más cosas
                break;

            // Si no es ni _FILES, _GET, _POST, _SESSION entonces:
            default:
                if ( empty(trim($_superglobal[$field])) )
                    json_response("El campo '{$field}' está vacío");
                break;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Ahora, en temas prácticos no es muy óptimo que se diga. Pero es lo que buscas, cierto?

Comment: Bueno, es la misma solución que plantee sólo que usando un switch para separar todas las posibilidades. No es lo que busco pero está bien dejarla como solución alternativa.

Comment: @LuisArrieta Y qué es exactamente lo que buscas? Leí dos veces lo que pusiste y no termino de entenderlo.

Comment: no es que no hayas entendido. Tu solución funciona y el resultado es el que busco, pero hasta tú mismo aceptas que no es la solución más optima. Concretamente me gustaría aprender alguna forma de hacerlo diferente a compararlo con el mismo `$_FILES`